# Position du sujet avec le verbe « être »

Tags: verbes, ordre-des-mots, formulation-idiomatique, sujet

Quelqu'un pourrait-il/elle affirmer ou infirmer que les constructions telles que les suivantes, avec le verbe « être », sont correctes ? Elles semblent très inhabituelles. En isolation, elles semblent ne pas correspondre à un contexte particulier ;

> Dans les bois sont certains dangers.
>   Dans les disciplines scientifiques sont plusieurs à ne pas exiger trop de mathématiques.

Elles donnent l'impression d'être des substituts à des constructions avec « il y a », mais là encore, il n'y a rien de sûr.

Comment: Pour moi ceci a vraiment l'air d'un anglicisme où l'inversion sujet-verbe se fait dans de contextes pareils.

Comment: @LukeSawczak C'est en fait à partir de votre dernière question que ma présente question s'est insinuée dans mon esprit : «  Parmi mes collègues en formation à l'enseignement sont plusieurs qui disent « avoir besoin que » (suivi par le subjonctif) comme dans cet exemple : … ». Cela vous aurait-il échappé? Vous ne pensez pas ces formes correctes donc (sous la guise que je leur donne et peut-être dans votre phrase)? J'ai bien cherché à éplucher l'immense article du TLFi sur le verbe « être » mais rien ne m'a sauté aux yeux!

Comment: Un substitut à **il y a** ? Bhein... évidemment! Et rien d'autre. Cf Benveniste.

Comment: @LPH Oups ! Oui, cela m'a échappé.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans l'absolu, ce type d'inversion littéraire est possible et permet de mettre l'accent sur le complément.

La phrase :

> Certains dangers sont dans les bois.

peut être écrite, en mettant en valeur *dans le bois* :

> Dans les bois sont certains dangers.

On retrouve cette tournure dans :

> Au commencement était le Verbe.

La deuxième phrase n'est pas très heureuse à l'endroit :

> Plusieurs à ne pas exiger trop de mathématiques sont dans les disciplines scientifiques.

et l'inversion n'arrange rien :

> Dans les disciplines scientifiques sont plusieurs à ne pas exiger trop de mathématiques.

La phrase ayant motivé la question aurait donné, inversée et en isolant *plusieurs*, une phrase idiomatique dans certains contextes :

> Plusieurs, qui disent « avoir besoin que » (suivi par le subjonctif) comme dans cet exemple …, sont parmi mes collègues en formation à l'enseignement.

En revanche, *parmi mes collègues sont plusieurs qui disent…* n'est pas vraisemblable et doit être attribuée à une faute d'inattention, confirmée et corrigée depuis.